# Inserting element in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, insert

In the linked list when we perform **insertLast(int item)** function, we do the following steps:

```
struct node *temp;
struct node *newItem;
newItem = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp = head;
while(temp->next != NULL){
   temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next  = newItem;
newItem->next = NULL;
```

But if we do:

```
struct node *temp;
struct node *newItem;
newItem = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp = head;
while(temp != NULL){
   temp = temp->next;
}
temp = newItem;
newItem->next = NULL;
```

we get an error, why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop

```
while(temp != NULL){
    ...
}
```

will terminate with `temp == NULL`, that is after running past the end of the list. Then

```
temp = newItem;
```

assigns a pointer to a newly created object to the `temp` variable – but that has nothing to do with a list anymore.

Hence there is no reason for any 'error' (except that the new item does *not* get appended to a list).

Answer (score 0):

At the second block of code, you don't set the link from the last element to point to the newly inserted element.